# Page Setup menu option disabled in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My Page Setup option on the File menu is now disabled in Visual Studio 2012. I can print my source code but I cannot modify the page setup. I have uninstalled, deleted all of the applicable registry entries, and reinstalled the product to no avail.

Any insights on what may be causing the problem or how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you have [the color printing extension installed](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44)? According to the extension page, it works with VS2012 in addition to VS2010. It's also included in the Productivity Power Tools 2012. If so, it seems there are reports of this happening (see [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44#4354) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729531/it-manager), for instance), but no solution.

Comment: Also, another report [partway down the page here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44/view/Reviews/2). If you do have it installed, try uninstalling or disabling just that.

Comment: Thank you very much, jerry! It was the Productivity Power Tools that was causing the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped, I'll post it as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the [Color Printing Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44) for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, which is also included as a part of [Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd). It's been [reported as a bug to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729531/it-manager) (emphasis added):

> I've installed the color printing plug-in for Visual Studio 2010 and I've noticed two bugs. The first is **PAGE SETUP is disabled on the FILE menu**, so I am unable to select the page orientation and size. Secondly, when printing a large visual basic file, the program REMOVES lines of code at the bottom of the page from the print.

Unfortunately, as you can see from the linked page, it's doesn't seem as if the problem will be fixed anytime soon. If you need the Page Setup option back, you'll have to disable or uninstall the extension.